# Microsoft Ad SDK for UWP drinks memory

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I've this ad control in each of my app's pages

```
<UI:AdControl 
    ApplicationId="my app id"
    AdUnitId="my unit id"
    Height="50"
    Width="320"
    ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"
    IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

After a few navigation back and forth it causes a memory leak and app crashes. as simple as that.

What can I do to avoid this? is there a way to have one instance of this control globally and use it in each page?

Thanks.

Comment: The way I did it is, I created one AdControl that's shared across all pages. Whenever a navigation happens, I trigger a refresh on the control.

Comment: @JustinXL I show two ads in wide screen, one in medium and one in small for mobiles. each one has a specific width and height. and each in a different location..